# use datediff to return records with at leats two days difference

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I do have a SQL Anywhere table with a date field called "fecha_inicio", a valid value for this field is 12/12/2017 and now I need to create a statement that gets all the records from the table which fecha_inicio is at least two days before the current date, this is what I have done for the moment

```
AND ((DATEDIFF(day, fecha_inicio, cast(getdate()as date)<=2)
```

but it doesn´t return any result or throw any exception, could you help me to improve this statement please

this is the whole sentence

```
"SELECT numero_orden, horario, accion_formativa FROM DBA.orden_inicio_af WHERE (numero_orden_inicio = ?) AND ((DATEDIFF(day, fecha_inicio, cast(getdate()as date)<=2) AND (estado_orden_inicio = '01' OR  estado_orden_inicio = '02' OR  estado_orden_inicio = '03') AND (nit = ?)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `datediff()` on the column.  Instead, compare directly to `getdate()`.  This is much better for the optimizer.

I think you intend:

```
where fecha_inicio < dateadd(day, -2, cast(getdate() as date))
```